# globally set jquery mobile to mini

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'd like to globally set every element in my jquery mobile app that suports data-mini to use it. Is there a global way to do this with out having to add data-mini='true' to html every element?

Answer (score 3):

Today I ran into a similar issue. My requirement was to be able to change to the mini version on the fly as part of screen resolution detection. Anyway, ​`$('form *')​​​​​​​​.data('mini', true);` also did not work for me but I do have a workaround, however annoying it is. I have three elements that I need to 'mini-fy'. A button, a text input (well, really an email input) and a text area.

For the button I was able to use `$('button').buttonMarkup({mini: true});` I verified using a developer JS console that it does indeed work. From there I also found `$('textinput').textinput({mini: true})` in the jquerymobile docs, however this does NOT work for me.

Finally, after studying the DOM I tried simply adding the class "ui-mini" to the text input and text area, and it seems to work.

So to sum it up:

```
$('button').buttonMarkup({mini: true});
$('input').addClass('ui-mini');
$('textarea').addClass('ui-mini');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a registered [feature request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Feature-Requests), see [Ability to use data-mini by default or on an entire container](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4166#issuecomment-5273131).

Which means, the best you can do with current version is what you said, adding attribute to all form elements.

Assuming the mobile page won't have many elements, I wouldn't say it is an issue at all:

```
​$('form *')​​​​​​​​.data('mini', true);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have tried what you suggested and data-mini="true" is added to the markup but the actual controls are not any smaller. odd!

Comment: accidentially upvoted before I tested it :-( ... it does at least not work with jQuery 1.10.2 / FF 31.0: in Firebug/HTML view I can't see the added attribute, but I can find it in the DOM or via querying. But even `$('#mypanel').enhanceWithin()` afterwards did not help (`div#mypanel` wraps the button).

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, and the below is the simplest answer :

```
var $widgets = $.mobile.widgets;

$.each($widgets, function(widget) {
    $widgets[widget].prototype.options.mini = true;
});
```

---

Everything is fine, but ... **listview**  makes no changes.

---

So I have to add :

```
$('ul[data-role=listview]').find('a').addClass('ui-mini');
```

---

The added code above is so ugly that I have to substitute it with this :

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a class="ui-mini">Hello World</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just add ***ui-mini*** class manually, not too bad, more handsome ^o^